# Htmlunit mouseOver() does not trigger popup

Tags: mouseover, htmlunit, popover

I wrote the following test. It looks like the htmlunit mouseOver() function is not working (I don't see the html code of the popover).
Am I missing something? How can I solve this issue?

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    try {

        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        HtmlPage currentPage = client.getPage("http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/");
        String xpath = "//a[@title='jTip Style!']";
        HtmlElement elm = (HtmlElement) currentPage.getByXPath(xpath).get(0);
        xpath = "(//img[@src='kids-drop-sand.jpg'])[1]";
        HtmlPage newPage = (HtmlPage) elm.mouseOver();
        Assert.assertTrue(newPage.getByXPath(xpath).size() > 0, "Popover is not displayed");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception thrown in " + this.getClass().toString()
                + " " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the latest svn ?
http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html

Or with the last successed build :  http://build.canoo.com/htmlunit/buildresults?log=log20120530150012Lbuild.1963

The latest release available is quite old and manage poorly JS events.